# Google showing pages with ?page=2 urls

Tags: 6, navigation, meta-tags

In one Drupal 6 based site there are product pages like : example.com/product1, example.com/product2 etc but in Google search engine result pages(SERP) it is instead taking us on clicking to url's to like : example.com/product1?page=2 or page=1 or other pages and so on.

This site has Nodewords installed and has meta-description defined for each page. But in case of url's like example.com/product1?page=2 meta-description isn't appearing.

The front-page seems to be set to "/node" so I can see in the bottom of the front-page as 1,2,3,4 ... links for pagination.

I simply want Google to index the page like example.com/product1 and not example.com/product1?page=2.

Why this could be happening and how can I resolve it?

Comment: I've posted question related to this: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/88023/adding-rel-canonical-meta-tag-in-comment-paginated-node-pages

Answer (score 2):

Those links appear in Google's index because they're linked to on your site (presumably the pager generates those links for you) and you allow Google to crawl and index them.

If you do not want those pages to be crawled and indexed by Google, then you can disallow it by adding the following to the `robots.txt` for your site (btw.: this has little to do with Drupal):

```
Disallow:*?page=*
```

This will stop *googlebot* (and *msnbot*) from crawling the pages that is linked to with a link that contains this pattern.

Note that wildcards are not part of the Robot Exclusion Standards (but are supported by *googlebot* and *msnbot*), so don't expect any rule with wildcards to be widely recognised by robots.

Comment: Oh! Those page=2 are due to the comment pagination. Adding in the Disallow will simply remove the rankings of this page from Google index .. dangerous. Shouldn't I add rel=canonical in such pages to the main page?

Answer (score 1):

To add another side to what Gisle Hannemyr already wrote - once Google has your links indexed, it might be hard to get rid of them. But there is no need.

First, there is a [Global Redirect](https://drupal.org/project/globalredirect) module to seamlessly redirect you to the "main" version of your node, no matter what way user accessed it. So you usually don't need to get rid of all that power these links give you.

With pager it might be a bit hard. If there is a real pager, you don't want to disallow Google indexing. Instead, providing good link "go to first page" would be useful.

In your case it's a pager of paginated thing that's not really a content. So you cannot simply redirect. [Canonical URL](https://drupal.org/project/canonical_url) module or more recent **[Nodewords](https://drupal.org/project/nodewords) module** allows Google to index all links, no matter to which page, but tells Search Engine that user should be directed to the canonical address, the one without `?page=1` part.

For Drupal 7, use [Metatag](https://drupal.org/project/metatag) module to provide canonical location.

Comment: But Canonical URL module says it's deprecated in preference to Nodewords

Comment: @user5858 OK, fixed. I'm using D7 now, missed that this good old fellow got deprecated.