# Adding rel=canonical meta tag in comment paginated node pages

Tags: 6, meta-tags

I posted this question: [Google showing pages with ?page=2 urls](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/87961/google-showing-pages-with-page-2-urls) and also read this post from Google: http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.in/2013/04/5-common-mistakes-with-relcanonical.html

I understand that node comments whether paginated or not are of low importance with respect to the node content itself. So all the paginated node pages reached by clicking links in the bottom just above "Post New Comment"( as in attachment) should have rel=canonical pointing to the main node page.

So these pages:

- example.com/node?page=1
- example.com/node?page=2 and so on

should have "rel=canonical" in the head section of html page pointing to example.com/node.

Though as mentioned in the Google's blog, even "rel=prev" or "rel=next" may also be desirable in case of such urls.

So I need help how to add rel=canonical in those paginated node page. How can I do it?
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google showing pages with ?page=2 urls](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/87961/google-showing-pages-with-page-2-urls) - Please edit your old questions if they was unclear, not repost. Unless it's significantly different, that is.

Comment: In this one I'm asking about specific implementation. And in the previous I wanted to know the reason of Google indexing those URL's

Comment: Then previous should be closed as off-topic or deleted.

Comment: But isn’t the previous question related to Drupal? Those URL's are due to the comments.

Comment: You should not use `rel`-`canonical` there, unless the canonical URL contains *all* comments.

Comment: @unor why? Can you pl. explain?

Comment: @user5858: The canonical content needs to be a) duplicative or b) a superset. But your canonical page doesn’t contain all the comments, which makes it neither duplicative nor a superset. - See also [this answer](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/45609/24166).

Answer (score -1):

It can be done using [Nodewords](https://drupal.org/project/nodewords) module as described [here](http://alvinalexander.com/drupal/drupal-canonical-meta-tag-pager-urls):

> Nodewords project allows you to add meta tags to Drupal pages, both
>   manually and automatically based on various settings. Paying attention
>   to meta tags, such as keywords, description and canonical URL, may
>   help obtain better search engine positioning.