# Adding rel=canonical meta tag in comment paginated node pages in Drupal 7

Tags: meta-tags

This question is same as that of Drupal 6 question: [Adding rel=canonical meta tag in comment paginated node pages](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/88023/adding-rel-canonical-meta-tag-in-comment-paginated-node-pages/88226#88226) but for Drupal 7.

How can I add rel=canonical tag in the paged urls ( like ?page=1) pointing to the main version one?

I could find the feature in the Nodewords module in Drupal 6. But the Metatag counterpart in Drupal 7 does not seem to have any such option.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to the original suggests Nodewords. And D7 replacement of Nodewords  module is [Metatag](https://drupal.org/project/metatag) module, that supports canonical links.

> Meta tags have additional uses like the Open Graph Protocol used by Facebook, specifying the canonical location of content across multiple URLs or domains.

Comment: but in the D6 Nodewords there is checkbox option to enable rel=canonical tag for paginated urls. This same one is not there in the D7 version. This tag can be added per page in D7 but no special handling for the paginated urls.

Comment: @user5858 what special handling you need for pagination? If you will set canonical on a node, it will be there, the same on all pages - and that's what you need, isn't it?